# Print distinct values in an array

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have a column which is an array and would like the print the distinct count

```
Event
| project colors
```

---

**Present OutPut**

```
["Red", "Green", "Green", "Red"]
["Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow"]
```

---

**Expected**

```
["Red", "Green", "Green", "Red"] , 2
["Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow"], 1
```

Comment: Which language are you trying to do that in. In SQL it's pretty easy. You can use count and group by.
Can you share a column example?

Comment: the language is the ms-app-analytics query language :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you want, using `todynamic` and `mvexpand` and `summarize`, (and `datatable` to create the input data)

```
// create your sample data using datatable to make a 'fake' table
datatable (colors: string) [
'["Red", "Green", "Green", "Red"]',
'["Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow"]'
]
// this part is answering your question
| extend c = todynamic(colors) // turns colors into arrays
| mvexpand c // expands all the values out of colors into their own rows (but each column value is still "dynamic" type)
| extend c = tostring(c) // turn the dynamic c column to strings to summarize the values
| summarize ["Count"] = dcount(c) by colors // count up distinct c values by each row
```

that will output what you have in your question:

```
colors                                     Count 
------------------------------------------------
["Red", "Green", "Green", "Red"]           2 
["Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow"]   1
```